What is this metal component with 0512A and 73472 printed on the side?
I received a large amount of great stuff from someone who stopped doing electronics as a hobby and I am going through it all now. I can identify all components, except for this one.
It is a two-lead metal component with a screw top (including a nut), with the markings 73472 and 0512A. Both lead to no useful information on Google.
See images below.


Does anybody know what this is?

Check for diode continuity between the leads both directions and the each lead to case, both directions. I'd reckon a diode with stud mounting for cooling but put the info into your question. One of the cheap eBay component testers would be useful to you right now!

It's a stud-mount thermistor, similar to this one.

